# Varying type of mysql php request

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am connecting to `mysql` database from `php` and making 3 quires (see the code below). Everything works fine, however, when I am checking the performance this php script takes from `0.5 - 2.5` secs. What could be the possible reason for such a difference in time? Do you have any advice, in general, on how to increase the performance of the script (maybe optimise the requests or use other functions)? The `fingerprint` and `IP` columns are indexed. Thanks indeed!

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user1', 'pass1', 'db1');

$sql = 'INSERT INTO Test '. 
        '(token, result, Link, IP, useragent, resolution, language, screen, fingerprint) '. 
        'VALUES ("' .$_GET['token_']. '", "OK", "ststsebhoupe", "'.$_GET['addr_'].'", "'.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].'", "'.$_GET['flag_'].'", "'.$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].'", "'.$_GET['screen_'].'", "'.$_GET['fingerprint_'].'")';  


$conn->query($sql);

$found1 = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Test WHERE `Link` = 'ststsebhoupe' and `fingerprint` = '".$_GET['fingerprint_']. "'")->fetch_row()[0];

$found2 = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Test WHERE `Link` = 'ststsebhoupe' and `IP` = '".$_GET['addr_']. "'")->fetch_row()[0];


$conn->close();
```

Comment: You can make a VIEW in MySQL for indeed make two querys for select info made only one and extract both values, this could rest the time of your process

Comment: Also you can build an Stored Procedure for let work the SQL engine instead of the server (in this case PHP) and your process could be optimizate in a 99%

Comment: First thing you can do is remove `COUNT(*)` and rather use primary key column (or any other NOT-NULL column in case no PK column exists) there instead like `COUNT(id)`.After that you can go with  @Fernando's suggestions

Comment: It would help to see the table definition and `EXPLAIN` query plans for each query.

Comment: @FernandoUrban - MySQL `VIEWs` are syntactic sugar; you get no performance benefit.

Answer (score 0):

To speed up *those* two `SELECTs`, create these two indexes on the table:

```
INDEX(Link, fingerprint)  -- in either order
INDEX(Link, IP)           -- in either order
```

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: @AlexNevsky - how many rows in the table?  Add those indexes; they should speed up the SELECTs.

Comment: As it mentioned above "The fingerprint and IP columns are indexed." Thanks

Comment: @AlexNevsky - `INDEX(fingerprint)` and `INDEX(Link, fingerprint)` are _different_ and optimize _different_ queries.  Please add the composite indexes I mentioned.